# jQuery UI interrupts CSS

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, dreamweaver

I have a perfect html webpage with CSS, and I would like to run a "datepicker" JQuery script.

The only problem is, when I add the required script

```
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../AllSet/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../AllSet/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"></script>


<script type="javascript"...
```

the webpage can not be seen in dreamweaver's design view, and everything appears to be missing.

Does this usually happen when you insert JQuery scripts?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to JQuery, and I can't seem to find the answers as to why this happens (and it happens almost every time).

Thanks!

Andrew

Comment: So, nothing to do with jQuery at all, then. This relates to jQuery UI. I've fixed the title and tags.

Comment: depending on what browser you're working in ie: Chrome (function F12 or Firefox = Firebug) open up the developer tools and click on console to see what errors you are receiving

Comment: Also, jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css and jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css are effectively redundant--you only need one or the other. They contain all the same rules, but the jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css version is compressed.

Comment: People still use a design view? I didn't realize they even still did them

Comment: @musefan I agree. Design View is not accurate whatsoever.

Comment: Really useful comments!

Answer (score 5):

Did you include jquery before including jquery-ui? Looking at your code it seems you haven't got jquery yet.

Good luck!